# How to fix Alexa problem requested skill response?

Tags: azure-functions, alexa-skills-kit

I've been working on an Alexa skill for a while. This skill was working fine for weeks but now I only get the response "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" anymore. When I send the same request wtih postman everthing works fine so the function app is not the problem. Then I thought ngRok might have been the problem and I uploaded the Azure function to the online platform. But still I get the same error.
Has anyone an idea of what might be wrong? The only thing I could think of is the endpoint but the url is correct and the Azure function works like it is supposed to.

When I used ngRok no requested even reaches my function, this is probaly also the case with the online Azure function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error means, that JSON that you send to alexa is malformed. Without seeing it, it's impossible to help, so if you can, add json response to the question. Another thing to check is logs. They should tell you what's wrong with or if you're testing on console, session ended request reason should give you more information in the 'request' tab. You can read more about this and other error messages in this alexa blog: [here](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/0d8c5234-3c7a-4b77-9906-b43a5310bde4/5-common-error-messages-for-custom-alexa-skills-and-how-to-troubleshoot-them).

Comment: I don't think the json was the problem because when I copied the json request from the console and sended it with postman it worked fine. Today I tried again and everything worked again, I have no idea what went wrong yesterday. I haven't changed anything since then. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate `Display Interface` in the interfaces panel.

On the left Menu, under "JSON Editor" you have "Interfaces".
Click on it and activate "Display Interface". Then, rebuild your Skill.

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-quiz-game/issues/33).